# Highcharts: useHTML for labels creates empty label div every time Axis.update() is called

Tags: highcharts

I took the jsFiddle from the "Highcharts Demo - VU meter" example and made a few changes to demonstrate my problem. My modified version: http://jsfiddle.net/kCpTt/

Inside the timer loop that updates the VU Meters I added this code to also call the update() method for each of the yAxis elements. (Note: In the code I am using in my project I actually pass some updates to the yAxis but those are irrelevant because this problem exists regardless of what gets passed in, including this empty object)

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({});
chart.yAxis[1].update({});
```

I also set just one of the yAxis labels to "useHTML:true" and left the other as default. If you inspect the labels (using Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools) you will see that every time the timer fires and it updates the data points, only the yAxis label that uses HTML gets an empty `<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="highcharts-axis-labels"></div>` left behind as it creates a new one for the label. The other one that does not use HTML does not get these orphaned divs.

Edit: I'm convinced this a bug so I filed an actual bug report: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1960

Edit 2: And just like that... the bug has been fixed. Awesome work. https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/9d60d9f4aaf5cdc266c1daabf43ccddc103d0115

Comment: Update is runing, becasue you have setInterval() function which is called each half a second. So when you remove this function then it will call only one time.

Comment: If you re-read my issue you will see that I know the interval is being called. I need the interval to run since that gets new data via a web service and updates the chart. (This is what the demo is doing with random.) I didn't add that part. And that is not the problem detailed in my post. The problem is that every time update() is called, the Axis with the labels using HTML gets an orphaned div that once held the old labels and a new div is created. This is clearly a bug in that Highcharts should be updating the contents of the label div rather than creating a new one when update() is called.

Comment: Sorry for a delay, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1981). Thanks!

Comment: In https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1960 @Jack.R.Abbit said that it has been addressed and fixed. Im running Highcharts JS v2.3.5 (2012-12-19) and as right now Im not able to update(is in production and no time..). Is there a fix that i can do?

Answer (score 0):

The new fix didnt help me so I made a hack.
On chart use the load event to remove the position from the bugged div

```
events: {
            load: function(event) {
                $('#YOURCONTAINER div.highcharts-container div.highcharts-axis-labels').css("position", "");
            }
        }
```